# unable to remove previously synced google account

Tags: factory-reset, google-account

I did a factory reset on my ZTE Grand X view 2 phone and forgot to remove my account before resetting it. Then, it was asking me for previously synced google account in order to unlock the phone. I typed my Gmail but it is saying that my google account is not correct and wouldn't unlock the phone.

Then, I did some search online to bypass the google account and successfully achieved it by using the talkback and quick shortcut maker method. Now, that I have bypassed the google account the device is unlocked but I'm unable to use the google apps because it still asks me to enter the previously synced id. If I restart or power off the device, it locks the device again and asks for previously synced google account.

I have tried to factory reset the device from the settings and that also locks the device again.

Any suggestions on how can I remove the previously synced account after I have bypassed it and unlocked the device?